# Where does initscript come from?

Tags: gradle

I am just curious about where the `initscript` method of init.gradle script comes from.

according to [the gradle official documents](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html), a `initscript` method can be used to configure init.gradle script and a init.gradle script configure against a Gradle object. And we also know every gradle script implementing Script. So I guess `initscript` must be a method of [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle.html) or [Script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Script.html). I refered to the official gradle dsl reference to search the definition of `initscript` but no definition was found in [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle.html) or [Script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Script.html). So, where are the definition of initscript? Is it a method of Gradle of Script?

Comment: Tried as lance-java suggested, I get the answer: the Object be configured in init.gradle is `InitScript`, which has a method `initScript`. Gradle DSL reference doesn't make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not find out for yourself?

```
initscript {
   throw new Exception("foo")
}
```

Then run something like

```
gradle tasks --stacktrace
```